# SAP on Windows running on Mac

Tags: windows, mac, sap

It is clear from some of the posts (answers) here that Windows can be installed in an Apple Mac. I would like to know whether SAP, which supposedly needs some high configuration with respect to RAM, be installed on a Windows system running a on Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you intend to use windows on mac:

**1: Using bootcamp**

If you use bootcamp to install windows on your mac then your running "on the metal" so to speak so you can expect the system to run at 100% of your macs hardware so if this meets the minimum spec of SAP then you should be fine.

**2: Virtual Machine**

The other option is to user a virtual machine such as Virtual Box or VMware.  Both of these packages allow you to customise how much HDD and RAM you assign to your windows vm machine. So you need to make sure you give adequate amounts of both to run your applications, SAP doesnt use 3d so I dont think you need to worry about the lack of/ Flakey 3d support in Virtual Box. Virtual machines never run at "on the metal" speeds but can get pretty close.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. also on using bootcamp, firstly i dont know anything about using mac.. the specs that would require for running sap on windows would be like 3gb RAM and 350GB of disk space. there are some SAP tools which mac doesnt support, so there wont be any problem for me running them on this windows (of mac)?

Comment: You don't have to worry about incompatiblitys with MAC OSX  when using bootcamp because it's windows that your booting and using

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read, SAP ERP 6.0 appears to require a bare minimum of about 4 GB of memory and 300GB of disk space.

SAP ERP should install in such a system as long as there is sufficient memory and disk space.

See this SAP Community Network Forums post: http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=449254

Comment: the mac that im buying is having 4gb of memory and 350GB of disk space.. so it shouldn't pose a problem with respect to that.. but can that be installed and run in the windows which inturn installed on a mac is what i would like to know.